# Handling shortcuts from context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keyboard-shortcuts, contextmenu

I have a Windows Form shown as a model dialog. It has a context menu of class `ContextMenuStrip`. I set shortcuts to several items in the context menu. But this shortcuts works only when context menu is shown. How to make them work even if the context menu is not activated?

The only way I know is to handle `KeyPress` event of the form, iterate recursively through all the items in the context menu and compare its `ShortcutKeys` property with the actual key pressed. If the match, manually call `OnClick` event for this item. Any better ideas?

Comment: Well I am not sure why the shortcut doesn't work when context menu is not activated, but one suggestion, when you handle the key press event and you determine the key combination, just call the function related to key combination. Why to iterate over contextmenus programatically?

Comment: Because that allows me to avoid code duplication. I want to have shortcuts in menu, so I must specify them there, and must set handlers there. And this should be the only place where I specify both.

Comment: One suggestion i can give you is, try to use ctrl key to generate shourtcut and see if it is working when the menu is closed?

Comment: Don't sure what you mean. I set shortcuts `Ctrl+1`, `Ctrl+2`, ..., they work when menu is activated and don't work when it is not shown.

Comment: I was trying to say the same. to have shortcuts like Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2. Actually Alt key activate the menu. May be you should try like Alt+1, Alt+2

Comment: Alt key activates main menu. I'm talking about context menu, it is activated by right mouse click.

Comment: You are right. This is an interesting question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.messagefilter.aspx I found a class called message filter. This helps you intercept the message generated before event is raised or any handler is executed. I think  this should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've implemented manual iteration in the `KeyPressed` event handler:

```
  Action<ToolStripMenuItem> check_shortcut = null;

  check_shortcut = (node) =>
  {
    if (node.ShortcutKeys == e.KeyData)
    {
      node.PerformClick();
    }
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem child in node.DropDownItems)
    {
      check_shortcut(child);
    }
  };

  foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in MyContextMenuStrip.Items)
  {
    check_shortcut(item);
  }
```

Comment: I've edited your answer: Some corrections, the correct event is KeyDown. In the foreach you need to check if the object is a ToolStripMenuItem, because if it a separator, an exception will be raised.

Comment: And maybe you have to set `KeyPreview=true;` on the form to ensure all KeyDown events are checked for.

Comment: Also, if your menu contains Separators you should change the `node.DropDownItems` with `node.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())` to prevent cast error exception checking shortcut only to ToolStripMenuItem objects.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ToolStripMenuItem.ShortCutKeys property, so that you no need to iterate and call the event handlers.

Sample Code:

```
ContextMenuStrip _contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
var menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Copy");
menuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.C;
_contextMenuStrip.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening the `ContextMenuStrip` in code or is the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the `Form` set to the `ContextMenuStrip` you created? If it's being opened in code, are you able to set the `Form` property instead? That should let you do the shortcut without having to open  the menu first.

Comment: That is actually the right answer. No need for manual filtering of keypress events.